# Infinite recursion using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React's State Hook in a functional component for getting therapist from database. From which I seen, in useEffect() where **setTherapists([therapists].concat(therapists));** is, the list is called in an infinite recursion. I can't see where the problems is, or how do I need to proper call the list.

After I correct get the therapists array I need to render all the therapist. This is how I thought about, but I don't know exactly how to write with Hooks State:

```
function renderTherapists()  {
    const items = this.state.therapists.map( (t, idx) => (
        <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
    ))

    return (
        <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
            { items }
        </div>
    )
}
```

My current functional component:

```
function TypeArticleOne(props) {

const [ therapists, setTherapists ]= useState([]);
const [speciality, setSpeciality]= useState('ABA');
const [pageLoading, setPageLoading]= useState(true);

const topProfilesUrl = 'therapists/top/profiles'

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(speciality);
    getTopTherapists();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

}, []);

const getTopTherapists = () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    loadTopTherapists();

};

const loadTopTherapists = () => {
    console.log("second");
    props.actions.reqGetTherapistsTopProfiles({
        body: {},
        headers: null,
        resource: `${topProfilesUrl}`
    })
};

useEffect(() => {
        let apiData = props.apiData;

    if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
        const therapists = apiData.topProfiles.therapists;
        setPageLoading(false);
        setTherapists([therapists].concat(therapists));

    }

    }, [pageLoading, therapists]);
```

Comment: `this.state.therapists` in a functional component? It is not a valid code

Comment: @DennisVash second part is the functional component

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Therapists coming in the props to the default value of your useState declaration:

```
const [ therapists, setTherapists ] = useState(apiData.topProfiles.therapists);
```

So when it's re-rendered, it doesn't get called again in a loop.

The constant therapists is shadowing the therapist list from your outer scope.

```
if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
    const therapists = apiData.topProfiles.therapists;
    setPageLoading(false);
    setTherapists([therapists].concat(therapists));

}
```

Also, as it's already an array, you can call the concat method without put the list within brackets [].

Like:

```
const loadedTherapists = apiData.topProfiles.therapists;
setPageLoading(false);
setTherapists(therapists.concat(loadedTherapists));
```